# Javascript For loop appends same element once

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, appendchild

This is to understand the logic of JS Loop. In the following code i expect that the `<li>` element will append 3 times inside the `<ul>` tag. So that i should get 3 `<li>` tag inside the `<ul>` tag. As per my understanding any actions inside the loop will work based on the condition. As per that  I should get 3 blank `<li>` tag here. But i get only 1. Anyone can explain whats wrong on my approach and how should i need to write it. Thanks in Advance!

```
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let li = document.createElement("li");
for (i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: You are appending the same element 3 times. If you want to have 3 elements, you have to create 3 elements. Create them inside the for loop.

Comment: Also PLEASE use <3 instead of <=2 - you want 3 elements, now we know you want 3 elements

Comment: @cloned your answer is valuable. Let me ask you that 'creation' method of element should not repeat in loop. I mean once we are already created the <li> tag. Can we repeat that already created <li> tag here instead of again creating it for 3 times. Hopes you understand my confusion.

Comment: @RenJitsm maybe you should read the API first, which will help you understand why your code not work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a *new* element each time. If you are appending the **same** element multiple times, it will move it in the DOM, but not clone it.

One simple solution is use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```js
let node = document.createTextNode("")
for (i = 0; i <3; i++) 
  document.body.appendChild( node.cloneNode() )
```

Note:

> Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (inline) listeners. It does not copy event listeners added using

Comment: Hi vsync It works! Wonderfull Solution. I also able to Loop through Array using your solution. Thank You very much!